# Adding multi-threading possibility to a single-threaded all-files-in-directory iterator utility function

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7, executor

I have a function that serially (single-threaded-ly) iterates through a directory of files, changing all tab indentation to three-space indentation.

I'm using it as my first attempt at multi-threading. (Am *most* of the way through [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)...surprised it's eight years old now.)

In order to keep it's current single-threaded functionality, but add in the additional possibility of multi-threading, I'm thinking of changing the function to accept an additional [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) parameter, where the original single-threaded function would now be a call to it, passing in a [single threaded executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()).

Is this an appropriate way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is as @Victor Sorokin suggests in his answer: wrap the processing of every file in a `Runnable` and then either submit to an `Executor` or just invoke `run()` from the main thread.

Another possibility is to **always** do the same wrapping in a `Runnable` and submit it to an **always-given** `Executor`.

Whether processing of each file is executed concurrently or not would depend on the given `Executor`'s implementation.

For parallel processing, you could invoke your function passing it i.e. a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) as an argument, whereas for sequential processing you could pass in a fake `Executor`, i.e. one that runs submitted tasks in the caller thread:

```
public class FakeExecutor implements Executor {

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        task.run();
    }
}
```

I believe this way is the most flexible approach.

Comment: Is there a difference between executing the task immediately, and doing it through a one thread thread pool (single-threaded executor)?

Comment: @aliteralmind Yes! Executing the task immediately means that everything executes sequentially. While executing with a single threaded executor runs it in parallel.

Comment: A single thread executor, such as [`Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) can't run things in parallel. I thought there might be some other differences.

Comment: @aliteralmind Of course it runs tasks in parallel. One at a time, but not on the caller thread. The caller thread continues its execution concurrently with the submitted task, which is executed in the background.

Comment: @aliteralmind Actually it's very easy to test it. Submit a task that sleeps some seconds and prints something and print something different immediately after calling your function. You'll notice the difference in the output.

Comment: Oh, of course. I see. One thread *in addition to* the thread that created it. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 8, I've found `parallelStream` to be about the easiest way to implement multi-threading

```
    List<File> files = Arrays.asList(getDirectoryContents());
    files.parallelStream().forEach( file -> processFile(file));
```

If you want to be able to change between single-threaded and multi-threaded, you could simply pass a boolean flag

```
    List<File> files = Arrays.asList(getDirectoryContents());
    if(multithreaded){
      files.parallelStream().forEach( file -> processFile(file));
    }else{
      files.stream().forEach(file -> processFile(file));
    }
```

I wish I could help with Java 7, but I went from Java 5 to 8 overnight.  :)  Java 8 is sooooooo worth it.

Comment: I'm using Java 7. Added the tag. Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Most straight-forward way:

1. (The most tricky part) Make sure code is thread-safe. Unfortunately, it's hard to give more concrete advice w/o seeing actual code in question;
2. Wrap code into `Runnable\Callable` (either anonymous class or explicit class which `implements Runnable\Callable`;

This way you'll be able either call your `Runnable` in main thread (single-threaded version) or pass it to an `Executor` (multi-threaded version).

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to create a class implements Executor interface which will execute your code in the main thread. Like this:

```
public class FileProcessor implements Runnable {

    private final File file;

    public FileProcessor(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something with file
    }
}

public class DirectoryManager {

    private final Executor executor;

    public DirectoryManager() {
        executor = new Executor() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Runnable command) {
                command.run();
            }
        };
    }

    public DirectoryManager(int numberOfThreads) {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    }

    public void process(List<File> files) {
        for (File file : files) {
            executor.execute(new FileProcessor(file));
        }
    }
}
```

and call it in your code like this

```
DirectoryManager directoryManager = new DirectoryManager();
directoryManager.process(lists);
// some other sync code
```

or this

```
DirectoryManager directoryManager = new DirectoryManager(5);
directoryManager.process(lists);
// some other async code
```

Comment: I have not seen the previous answers, in general, I wrote the same thing as @Magnamag