# Optional debugging output in a multi-threaded application--I mean *for the client*, not for the sake of figuring out deadlocks or bugs

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7

I'm working on [my first multi-threaded application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263326/adding-multi-threading-possibility-to-a-single-threaded-all-files-in-directory-i), for the sake of learning. I really need to learn it. I already have a single-threaded function that reads in all text files in a directory, and replaces all indentation tabs to three spaces.

It has the ability to pass in an [`Appendable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) for the sake of optional extra information (listing each file, giving statistics, etcetera). If they pass in `null`, they want no debugging.

I'm trying to determine what's the best way of handling this in a multi-threaded version, but searching for "debugging multi-threaded java" is giving me nothing but how to diagnose bugs and deadlocks.

Can I safely stick with an Appendable or should I be considering something else? I'm not sure how to deal with interleaving messages, but the first thing I want to figure out is thread safety.

Comment: You wouldn't prefer to use a standard logging library?

Comment: @sudocode Inexperienced and unfamiliar with "proper" logging. Not against it. Have always done it by passing in an Appendable.

Comment: Yea, definitely consider a logging library, especially since it handles synchronization for you in multi-threaded apps.

Comment: As I said, I've never written a multi-threaded app before, so up to this point, using an Appendable has fit the bill just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing in an `Appendable`, consider using [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) in your library to do the logging.

If no logging framework is linked in at run-time, no logging will be done.  If the application is doing logging already, then there's probably a front-end to it that slf4j will output to.

I'd recommend using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) for your logging output, as it's nicely configurable, either through configuration files or directly in code.  All you need to do to get rudimentary output is include the JAR.

Comment: Am running through the tutorials now. One question: I understand...I believe...putting the binding jar on the classpath is how you choose to turn logging on or off *as a whole* (by either using NOP--or *no*--jar, or the log4j jar or for whatever other framework you choose). What I don't get yet, is how do you turn logging on for one class, but off for all others?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using [Appendable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) from multiple threads is that it is not specified as thread safe.

> Thread safety is the responsibility of classes that extend and implement this interface.

The answer is therefore to use a thread-safe multiplexor. This one uses a `BlockingQueue` and a thread that pulls data out of it and forwards it to their `Appendable`.

```
class TellThemWhatIsHappening implements Appendable {

    // The pipe to their system/log.
    private final Appendable them;
    // My internal queue.
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    // Hav I been interrupted?
    private volatile boolean interrupted = false;

    public TellThemWhatIsHappening(Appendable them) {
        // Record the target Appendable.
        this.them = them;
        // Grow my thread.
        Thread t = new Thread(consumer);
        // Make sure it doesn't hold your app open.
        t.setDaemon(true);
        // Start the consumer runnning.
        t.start();
    }

    // The runnable that consumes the queue and passes it on to them.
    private Runnable consumer = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!interrupted) {
                try {
                    // Pull from the queue and push to them.
                    them.append(queue.take());
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    // We got interrupted.
                    interrupted = true;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Not sure what you shoudl do here. Their appendable threw youy an exception.
                    interrupted = true;
                }
            }
        }

    };
```

Continued...

```
    private void append(String s) throws IOException {
        // No point if they are null.
        if (them != null) {
            try {
                queue.put(s);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // What should we do here?
                interrupted = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Appendable append(CharSequence csq) throws IOException {
        append(csq.toString());
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Appendable append(CharSequence csq, int start, int end) throws IOException {
        append(csq.subSequence(start, end).toString());
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Appendable append(char c) throws IOException {
        append("" + c);
        return this;
    }

}
```

However - it is a very good idea to use a proper logging system for logging rather than growing your own.

Comment: Very nice to see how what I know is translated into the multi-threaded universe. I need this.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging threads is often a case of trying to figure out presentation.  Log4j is great generally.  You can configure it to tag each line with the thread name as well as the timestamp.  Once you do this you can filter the output based on thread name and follow a single thread.

A good filtering tool is really important.  The most basic would be tail and pipe it through grep--but if it's something you do a lot you might want to layer something on top of the log--like a GUI with tabs for each thread or something like that.

Log4j itself will have no problem dealing with threads.

If you really want to do it yourself, pass in a DIFFERENT appendable to each thread, then when the thread is done dump it or save it to a file.  You probably want to use just one thread to dump/save the appendables.